# Solve for $x$: $\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{2}-1}}{\sin x}+\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{2}+1}}{\cos x}=2\sqrt[4]{8}$

Tags: trigonometry

Solve for $x$.
$$\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{2}-1}}{\sin x}+\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{2}+1}}{\cos x}=2\sqrt[4]{8},\quad 0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$$

I need some hints on where to start. How do I approach this trigonometry problem?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Yes, I've tried using a graphical method on demos, but that isn't in the nature of the question. I also tried multiplying both sides by sqrtsqrt2+1 but that didn't work. I also tried squaring both sides but that doesn't work either. Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

Look at the terms $\sqrt{\sqrt{2}-1},\sqrt{\sqrt{2}+1}$. Consider writing them as $\sin A,\cos A$ for some $A$. Is it possible? The answer is no because the values should be limited by $-1$ and $1$. Suppose after multiplying by some constant, the condition is satisfied. A property they must satisfy would be $$\sin^2 A+\cos^2 A=1.$$ In relation with this, we do the following.
$$(\sqrt{\sqrt{2}-1})^2+(\sqrt{\sqrt{2}-1})^2=\sqrt{2}-1+\sqrt{2}+1=2\sqrt{2}\\\Rightarrow\frac{(\sqrt{\sqrt{2}-1})^2+(\sqrt{\sqrt{2}-1})^2}{2^{3/2}}=1$$
Set $$\sin A=\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{2}-1}}{2^{3/4}}\quad\text{and}\quad\cos A=\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{2}+1}}{2^{3/4}}.$$
Verify that these lie in the interval $[-1,1]$.
Multiply both sides of your problem equation by $2^{-3/4}$ and rewrite it as
$$\frac{\sin A}{\sin x}+\frac{\cos A}{\cos x}=2\times2^{3/4}\times2^{-3/4}=2\\\Rightarrow \sin A\cos x+\sin x\cos A=2\sin x\cos x\\\Rightarrow\sin(A+x)=\sin2x$$
You have $x\in(0,\pi/2)$. Write the general solution of the following as an equation in terms of $(A+x),2x$. Given a domain, you should be able to narrow down the solutions.